# I want to change the install location of apt so I have room on my disk

Tags: apt, software-installation

I'm installing Dolphin emu and I'm not going to have space on my SSD where my Ubuntu install is, so I want to install it on my HDD that way there's more than enough space to download game ISOs.  How do I do this?

Comment: The ISOs don't have to be on the same partition as dolphin. You can specify the folders that contain the ISOs, no matter where they are located.

Answer (score 2):

You CANNOT change the locations that apt installs to. Those locations are specified when the deb or snap package is created, and are not user-editable.

You CAN change which directories are housed on which drives (or partitions). Your Ubuntu filesystem can be split across multiple partitions by editing /etc/fstab/ and doing a bit of clever copying. Before experimenting with /etc/fstab, be sure to backup your data -- folks make mistakes, and fstab can be unforgiving of mistakes.

For example, using /etc/fstab you can move your ~/Downloads directory to a separate empty partition.

Comment: +1, I'd personally suggest to try it in a virtual machine first, though. Additionally, you don't have to manipulate the fstab if you do this at installation time. But I guess the OP's question was an xy problem anyway.